# undefined local variable or method `params'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I am using gem gibbon to connect my website devise user to mailchimp so here is my controller and I am not sure how can I find the user emails

Please someone help me

```
class SubscribeUserToMailingListJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
   require 'gibbon'


  def perform(*args)
    user = User.find(params[:id])

    gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "40691025ef57db1d1be9530e5d6ed79d-us7")
    gibbon.timeout = 10
    gibbon.lists("f9acb10acd").members.create(
            body: 
            {
                email_address: user.email, 
                status: "subscribed"})

  end
end
```

Comment: JFYI, this is not a controller.

Comment: Oh ye so how can I find the user email This is in the user model  def subscribe_user_to_mailing_list
    SubscribeUserToMailingListJob.perform_later(self)
  end

Comment: What do you mean, how can I find? You're passing a user object in args. User has email.

Comment: email_address: User.email it give me undefined method `email' for #<Class:0x007ff618f68dd8>

Comment: hint: inspect what you have in `args`

Comment: Your awesome I changed it to id and it worked I copied the arg from somewhere.

Comment: You can add your answer to mark it if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a user in the args already. Just name it accordingly.

```
def perform(user)
  # now you can do
  user.email
```